Interior of a set with right ray topology
I'm studying topology by my own and in a certain page of a book I have been asked to find the interior of the set $A = (0,1)$ with the right ray topology, whose basis is $B = (a,+\infty), a \in \mathbb{R}$. However, in several webpages I have seen that the answer is that the interior is the set itself, which is not my answer since I think that the interior would be the empty set. Here is my reasoning:

The interior $int(A)$ is the set of all elements $p$ such that there exists a neighbourhood $V$ such that $p \in V$ and $V \subseteq A$. However, there isn't any open set of the topology such that it is contained in $A$ since each open set in this topology has the form $(a,+\infty$), so, wouldn't be the interior the empty set?

Yes, you are correct.

Thanks, because in some webpages I have seen that the interior is $(0,1)$. By the way, the closure of this set $\overline{A}$ would be $(-\infty,2)$, right?

I believe the closure would be $(-\infty, 1]$.

Sorry, I meant $1$ instead of $2$

The complement of $(-\infty, 1)$ is $[1,\infty)$ which is not open.

The interior of a set is its largest open subset. In your problem, the interval $(0, 1)$ does not contain any basis elements (since any basis element necessarily contains an element that is larger than $1$). Therefore, you are correct that ${\rm Int} (0, 1) = \emptyset$.
The closure of $(0, 1)$ is the set of all points $x$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $(0, 1)$. Consider any element $x$ less than $1$. It is easy to see that every neighborhood of $x$ will contain the point $\frac{1}{2} (\max \{ 0, x \} + 1) \in (0, 1)$, so $x \in {\rm Cl} (0, 1)$. The point $x = 1$ is also in the closure, because any neighborhood of $1$ necessarily contains some basis element of the form $(y, \infty)$, where $y < 1$; again, we see that the point $\frac{1}{2} (\max \{ 0, y \} + 1) \in (0, 1)$. But for any point $x > 1$, the neighborhood $\left( \frac{1}{2} (1 + x), \infty \right)$ of $x$ is disjoint from $(0, 1)$. Therefore, ${\rm Cl} (0, 1) = (-\infty, 1]$.
Perhaps an easier way to see this is that in your topology, all nontrivial open sets (not just basis elements) are of the form $(x, \infty)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ - I'll leave it to you to show that this is the case. To find the closure, we can find the largest open set $U$ that is disjoint from $(0, 1)$ (this is sometimes called the exterior). Clearly, we have $U = (1, \infty)$, from which we determine ${\rm Cl} (0, 1) = \mathbb{R} - (1, \infty) = (-\infty, 1]$.
